# What happended to robot replay and are there any other services like that?

Tags: statistics, user-interaction

A couple of years ago I tried robot replay's service where I could, by adding a script on a site, replay what the users were doing. Mouse movement, scrolling, clicks etc. It was pretty cool and can be really useful.

What happended to them? I can't go to their site anymore.

Is there any other service like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the original creator of RobotReplay. That service was acquired by a company called ForeSee Results (www.foreseeresults.com) and it's now called CS SessionReplay. It's no longer a free service but still stands head and shoulders above similar services in what it is able to capture in a technical sense. You can also look at ClickTale but many who try their service are disappointed except those with the simplest pure-HTML layouts.

Feel free to give ForeSee a call, however!